# Responsive Kinetic JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, kineticjs

I'm trying to make my Kinetic JS container responsive. At the moment this is my code.

```
    window.onresize = function(event) {  //this function will resize your stage to the size of your window
        stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        stage.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
        stage.draw(); //redraw the stage, not sure if really needed, but good to have.
    }

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'gamebox', // Find an HTML element
        width: window.innerWidth, // Set width
        height: window.innerHeight // Set heigth
    });
```

Instead of getting the innerWidth of the browser window I'd like to get the Width of a div Class as I'm using Bootstrap. Is it possible and if so how do you do it?

EDIT:
I finally solved my problem by chaning my code to this

```
window.onresize = function(event) {  //this function will resize your stage to the size of your window
    stage.setWidth($('.col-lg-6').width());
    stage.setHeight($('.col-lg-6').height());
    stage.draw(); //redraw the stage, not sure if really needed, but good to have.
}
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'gamebox', // Find an HTML element
    width: $('.col-lg-6').width(), // Set width
    height: $('.col-lg-6').height() // Set heigth
});
```

Comment: You should put your answer in the answer section and accept it when stackoverflow allows you too. Cheers